# Posted blocks on ethgasstation/Low gas price watchlist

Tags: gas, gas-price, ethgasstation

Does anyone understand the posted blocks on ethgasstation/Low gas price watchlist?
I would guess that `posted block < mined block` is always true - but this is not what I see there.[image: gasstation low gas price watchlist]